# Is there a 'get' like mapping method for a pandas Series?

Tags: python, pandas

Standard Python dicts come with the `get` method where one can specify the mapping value if no corresponding key is found. Is there any such method for applying a map to a Pandas Series such that I can substitute a fallback value?

As a workaround I see two routes possible to achieve this effect: manually invoke the get method for a dict by using the elemment wise `apply`, or chain a `map` followed  by a `fillna` which both have the advantage of being vectorized operations. However this is still two operations rather than one which I imagine would still outperform the apply call for large data sets. If I could get this done with one invocation all the better, just not sure if that's possible.

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame( { 'a':['a1','a2','a3'] } )
mapDict = {'az':'nothing' , 'a1':'hitit'}
df['aSeriesMap']     = df['a'].map( mapDict )
df['aSeriesMapFill'] = df['a'].map( mapDict ).fillna( 'NoKeyValue' )
df['applyMap']       = df['a'].apply( lambda r : mapDict.get( r , 'NoKeyValue' )  )

>>> df
    a aSeriesMap aSeriesMapFill    applyMap
0  a1      hitit          hitit       hitit
1  a2        NaN     NoKeyValue  NoKeyValue
2  a3        NaN     NoKeyValue  NoKeyValue
```

Comment: `.apply` is not vectorized (unless you apply a `ufunc`), and I'm not sure if `.map` is vectorized, at least, I don't think it will be unless you are mapping a `ufunc`.

Comment: I could indeed be off on that point, I was just assuming the bulk of the methods outside of the apply family was vectorized. I'll have to double check my notes and if this was covered in Sofia Heisler's [No More Sad Pandas](https://youtu.be/HN5d490_KKk) talk. Nothing glaring stands out for me in the [source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.21.0/pandas/core/series.py#L2188-L2316), although I'm not versed in the internals of pandas. It's an interesting question if there's some documentation notation or convention pandas uses to indicate whether a method is vectorized or not.

Comment: well, it looks like you are working with `dtype=object` anyway, which has no hope of being vectorized.

Comment: After digging, it seems `pd.Series.map` delegates to `lib.map_infer`, checking that out in the console `help(lib.map_infer)` I get a docstring that says `Substitute for np.vectorize with pandas-friendly dtype inference` so, if it *is* a substitute for `np.vectorize` that means, ironically, that it is *definitely not vectorized*, the [famous warning from `np.vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) clearly states "The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop."

Answer (score 2):

Why not to test them all:

```
In [11]: df = pd.concat([df] * 10**4, ignore_index=True)

In [12]: df.shape
Out[12]: (30000, 1)   # NOTE: our DF has 30.000 rows

In [13]: %timeit df['a'].map( mapDict )
4.9 ms ± 320 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [14]: %timeit df['a'].map( mapDict ).fillna( 'NoKeyValue' )
9.65 ms ± 806 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [15]: %timeit df['a'].apply( lambda r : mapDict.get( r , 'NoKeyValue' )  )
21.7 ms ± 96.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

one more option:

```
In [24]: %timeit np.where(df['a'].isin( mapDict ), df['a'].map( mapDict ), 'NoKeyValue')
6.97 ms ± 13.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```